# Split with lines in QGIS get stuck at a certain %

Tags: qgis, vector, splitting

I have a problem when using split with lines in QGIS. So I have two layers, First is land cover classes (closed forest, open forest, cropland, etc.), and Second is a management blocks. My task is to determine what land cover are present in each blocks and calculate their areas. here is my process:

1. make a separate vector file for each land cover class. Then process then individually.
2. Use the 'Split with lines' to divide the land cover polygon into their respective blocks.
3. Use Join attributes by location to include the block number in the land cover attributes.
4. calculate the area using 'statistics by category'.

So far everything is good I am already done with two land cover classes, now the problem starts when I'm doing the other two classes (Plantation and Mixed Vegetation), these land cover classes are the biggest among all the classes. When I'm doing the step two - 'split with lines' the processing got stuck at 64% (plantation) and 82% (Mixed Vegetation). I tried to wait thinking that maybe it is because of the size but it already took over an hour when it was usually just a minute, the processing is still stuck.
[image: This shows the land cover Plantation and the management blocks]
[image: This shows that the processing is stuck]

Comment: Do you use spatial index ?

Comment: Maybe the output file size is too big for shapefile. Try using geopackage.

Comment: What does your system say in regards of CPU usage, RAM and storage activity?

Comment: Try creating a polygon block layer instead of lines. Then [intersect](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisintersection) the blocks and land cover

Comment: Or Union might be better, to keep any land cover that is outside the grid